# How do I use php to feed data to jQuery autocomplete?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, jquery-plugins, autocomplete

I'm trying to build a form where certain text fields and text areas have autocomplete.

I've used the formidable plugin for wordpress to build my form. I'm using the [jQuery autocomplete plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete) for the autocomplete part.

The code looks like this:

```
<script>

            $(document).ready(function(){
                var data = "Core Selectors Attributes Traversing Manipulation CSS Events Effects Ajax Utilities".split(" ");
            $("#example").autocomplete(data);
  });
  </script>
```

So basically I need to use php to pull data from the mysql database and feed it to that data var. I'm a php newbie, so I'm not sure how to do this. A coder who works on the formidable plugin suggested the following code for the var data part:

```
 <?php
global $frm_entry_meta;
$entries = $frm_entry_meta->get_entry_metas_for_field($field_id, $order='');
?> //db_frm_entry_metas is the name of the mysql db that stores the values for every field from the form. I suspect get_entry_metas_for_field is a function added by the formidable plugin. $field_id is the id for a given field on the form. 
var data = new Array();
<?php foreach($entries as $value){ ?>
data[] = <?php echo $value ?>;

<?php } ?>
```

I tried to run this code with an id number in the place of $field_id, but it didn't work. I'm stuck here.

I can understand most of the code, except for this part:

```
var data = new Array();
<?php foreach($entries as $value){ ?>
data[] = <?php echo $value ?>
```

I don't get what the data[] is doing there... should the php be feeding the data to the var data= line?

I have around 15 form text/textarea fields, each of which needs to pull data associated with its given field_id. Unless there's an easier way to do this, this means I'll have to write 15 scripts, each with a particular $field_id and jQuery object with field's css selector.

Any help getting this to work would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The coder is wrong, this:

```
data[] = something;
```

will cause a syntax-error in JS, it's a PHP-shorthand for pushing members to an array and doesn't work in JS.

Try this:

```
data.push(unescape('<?php echo rawurlencode($value); ?>');
```

Comment: I'm going to go this route because the other two are way, way over my head. I tried plugging in the code you provided where the data[] = something; was. Still not working. Here's what the code looks like, it's in the body of page.php, a template which wordpress uses to generate static pages (the form is on one of these):

Comment: <script>
      
     $(document).ready(function(){
<?php
global $frm_entry_meta;
$entries = $frm_entry_meta->get_entry_metas_for_field(37, $order='');
?>

var data = new Array();

<?php foreach($entries as $value){ ?>

data.push(unescape('<?php echo rawurlencode($value); ?>');

<?php } ?>
    $("#field_name-of-the-school").autocomplete(data);
     })
     
 </script>

Comment: // 37 is the field id I want to pull from in the database, and #field_name-of-the-school is the css id for the the text field in the form where a user can enter the name of a school. the data for that field is stored in the db under field id 37. other fields, like school id, have their own field ids.

Answer (score 0):

According to the autocomplete docs, you can pass a url as the data parameter. That being said, do something such as the following:

```
<?php
  // --- PLACE AT VERY TOP OF THE SAME FILE ---
  $search = isset($_GET['q']) && !empty($_GET['q']) ? $_GET['q'] : null;
  if (!is_null($search))
  {
    $matches = Array();
    // some search that populates $matches based on what the value of $search is
    echo implode("\r\n",$matches);
    exit;
  }
?>
```

then, in your jQuery code replace the `.autocomplete(data)` with `.autocomplete('<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>');`

Answer (score 0):

your jquery will be something like this

```
$("#example").change(function(){
$.ajax( 
        { 
            type: "POST", 
            url: "php_page.php", 
            data: "data=" + $("#example").val(),
            beforeSend: function() {
                // any message or alert you want to show before triggering php_page.php
            },
            success: function(response) {
                eval(response);
                // print your results
            }

         });
});
```

in your php page after getting all info echo the results like this.

```
echo "var result=" . json_encode($results);
```

then eval(response) jquery function will give you javascript variable result with your results in it.
Hope this helps...