# How to use php to feed data to jQuery autocomplete?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, jquery-plugins, jquery-autocomplete

This is a continuation of an [earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262143/how-do-i-use-php-to-feed-data-to-jquery-autocomplete). Unfortunately, The solutions posted didn't work and my follow up questions weren't addressed. Just in case this is because my generous respondents didn't notice I had replied, I'm reposting my problem.

---

I'm trying to build a form where certain text fields and text areas have autocomplete.

I've used the formidable plugin for wordpress to build my form. I'm using the [jQuery autocomplete plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete) for the autocomplete part.

After implementing the suggestions of one of my respondents, the code now looks like this:

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){ 
<?php global $frm_entry_meta; 
$entries = $frm_entry_meta->get_entry_metas_for_field(37, $order=''); ?> 
var data = new Array(); <?php foreach($entries as $value){ ?>
data.push(unescape('<?php echo rawurlencode($value); ?>'); 
<?php } ?> 
$("#field_name-of-the-school").autocomplete(data); }) 
</script>

// 37 is the field id I want to pull from in the database, 
// and #field_name-of-the-school is the css id 
// for the text field in the form where a user can enter the name of a school. 
// the data for that field is stored in the db under field id 37. 
// other fields, like school id, have their own field ids.
```

My respondent suggested adding the `data.push(unescape('<?php echo rawurlencode($value); ?>');` bit. Unfortunately, it's still not working.

BTW, the code is in the body of page.php, a template which wordpress uses to generate static pages (the form is on one of these).

I would seriously, seriously appreciate any and all help with this. If this approach is a dead end (on the earlier posts, there were two other answers that were over my head,) I would be more than willing to learn some new tricks (though it would really help to be pointed to a relevant learning resource.)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would jsut use `json_encode` and simplify it:

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  <?php global $frm_entry_meta; 
  $entries = $frm_entry_meta->get_entry_metas_for_field(37, $order=''); ?> 
  var data = <?php echo json_encode($entries); ?>;

  $("#field_name-of-the-school").autocomplete({source: data});
});  // note you were missing a semicolon at the end of this, which i added
</script>
```

Of course using the above may not be waht you want if `$entries` is an associative array instead of a numeric indexed one. If thats the case you can do `json_encode(array_values($entries));`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
$("#field_name-of-the-school").autocomplete({ source : data });
```

as shown in the [Autocomplete documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) example. Also you might think
about using [JSON](http://json.org).